# How do I access class methods in a define_singleton_method block in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to access class methods within a `define_singleton_method` block, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is an example.

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :tags

  def initialize
    @tags = []
    @tags.define_singleton_method(:<<) do |val|
      val = tosymbol(val)
      push(val)
    end
  end

  def tosymbol(value)
    value = value.to_s
    value = value.gsub!(/\s+/,'_') || value
    value = value.downcase! || value

    return value.to_sym
  end
end
```

But when I use it I get an error.

```
test = Test.new
test.tags<<"Hello World"
NoMethodError: undefined method `tosymbol' for []:Array
  from /home/joebloggs/GitHub/repo/file.rb:183:in `block in initialize'
  from (irb):9
  from /home/joebloggs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

I tried changing `val = tosymbol(val)` to `val = Test::tosymbol(val)` but that didn't work either, I get `undefined method 'tosymbol' for Test:Class`

I could re-write what `tosymbol` is doing, but it wouldn't be very DRY. Where am I going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Try `def self.tosymbol`, then call `Test::tosymbol(val)`. What are you actually trying to do? Perhaps we can suggest a better way.

Comment: `def self.tosymbol` didn't work unfortunately. What I want to do is run a validation method against whatever is pushed to an instance variable. At the moment I'm trying to do that by overriding the instances `<<` method. The problem is that I want to reuse code I have elsewhere, and the `define_singleton_method` seems not to be able to see anything outside of itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where am I going wrong?

You're (**re**)defining a `<<` method for instance of `Array` class, not `Test` class.

While doing so you are trying to access `tosymbol` method, that is not defined in `Array` class, but in `Test` class.

What you want, *probably* (read *judging by your code sample*), is to define `<<` method for instances of `Test` class:

```
def initialize
  @tags = []
end

def <<(val)
  tags << tosymbol(val)
end

test = Test.new
test << "Hello World"
#=> [:hello_world]
```

## EDIT

To make your example to work you just need to assign the instance to a variable and call the `tosymbol` method with correct receiver:

```
def initialize
  @tags = []
  test = self # <============
  @tags.define_singleton_method(:<<) do |val|
    val = test.tosymbol(val)
    push(val)
  end
end
```

Now:

```
test.tags << 'Hello World'
#=> [:hello_world]
```

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't working for me. The `<<` on tags just acts like it normally does for an array, nothing in the `def <<(val)` method is happening (even puts).

Comment: @I_do_python sorry, I edited the answer, It should just be `test << "Hello World"`

Comment: Ok, that's working now, thanks. Is there anyway to make this specific to an instance variable though? As presumably this would mean you can only have a single array instance variable in the class. It's also not clear to the user that your appending to the tags variable (i.e. That the result of `test << 4` can be found under `test.tags`).

Comment: @I_do_python sure, let me edit the answer to make your try working